# Concurrency with a SINGLE WRITE by a single writer and multiple readers

Tags: go, concurrency, mutex, atomic, race-condition

NOTE: This question is different from other concurrency questions because not only the writer is single, but also the write operation happens **strictly once**.

What method of synchronization in Go to use when one has multiple concurrent readers and a single writer that writes once and only once, for example a setter in a concurrent environment?

`sync.Mutex` works for this case, however, since there is only one writer, `sync.RWMutex` is even better as it is marginally faster than a regular mutex.

Still, it feels wasteful to do the mutex locking for the duration of the application run to simply set a value once.

Is there a faster way?

```golang
package main

import (
    "sync"
)

type RWMutexErrorNotifier struct {
    rwMutex     sync.RWMutex
    emailSender func(string)
}

func (a *RWMutexErrorNotifier) SetEmailSenderService(emailSender func(string)) {
    a.rwMutex.Lock()
    defer a.rwMutex.Unlock()

    a.emailSender = emailSender
}

func (a *RWMutexErrorNotifier) SendErrorMessage(errorMessage string) {
    a.rwMutex.RLock()
    defer a.rwMutex.RUnlock()

    if a.emailSender == nil {
        return
    }

    a.emailSender(errorMessage)
}

func main() {
    sender := &RWMutexErrorNotifier{}

    errorsCount := 100_000

    emailSender := func(emailMessage string) {
        // sending email...
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup // used only for demo purposes

    wg.Add(errorsCount)

    for i := 0; i < errorsCount; i++ {
        go func() {
            sender.SendErrorMessage("ALARM!")
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    sender.SetEmailSenderService(emailSender) // making a single write

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED thanks to @peter-cordes - see comments below the answer

Apparently, reading and setting `atomic.Bool` is faster than `sync.RWMutex` for a single write by a single writer. It is only marginally slower than a no-lock racy solution (used only for benchmarking)

Benchmark results (`sync.Mutex`-based solution is also provided for benchmarking purposes only):

```bash
$ go test -run=XXX -bench=. -benchmem -benchtime=1000000x
goos: darwin
goarch: arm64
pkg: untitled1
BenchmarkRacyNoGoodConcurrently-12                       1000000              3529 ns/op             384 B/op         12 allocs/op
BenchmarkAtomicBooleanConcurrently-12                    1000000              3494 ns/op             384 B/op         12 allocs/op
BenchmarkRWMutexConcurrently-12                          1000000              3909 ns/op             384 B/op         12 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutexConcurrently-12                            1000000              4180 ns/op             384 B/op         12 allocs/op
BenchmarkRacyNoGoodSequentiallyAllCores-12               1000000                 3.661 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAtomicBooleanSequentiallyAllCores-12            1000000                 3.748 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkRWMutexSequentiallyAllCores-12                  1000000              1934 ns/op               0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutexSequentiallyAllCores-12                    1000000              1486 ns/op               0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkRacyNoGoodSequentiallySingleCore-12             1000000                28.95 ns/op            0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAtomicBooleanSequentiallySingleCore-12          1000000                29.54 ns/op            0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkRWMutexSequentiallySingleCore-12                1000000               188.6 ns/op             0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutexSequentiallySingleCore-12                  1000000               187.4 ns/op             0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      untitled1       19.093s
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
)

type ErrorNotifier interface {
    SetEmailSenderService(func(string))
    SendErrorMessage(string)
}

// Mutex

type MutexErrorNotifier struct {
    mutex       sync.Mutex
    emailSender func(string)
}

var _ ErrorNotifier = (*MutexErrorNotifier)(nil)

func (a *MutexErrorNotifier) SetEmailSenderService(emailSender func(string)) {
    a.mutex.Lock()
    defer a.mutex.Unlock()

    a.emailSender = emailSender
}

func (a *MutexErrorNotifier) SendErrorMessage(errorMessage string) {
    a.mutex.Lock()
    defer a.mutex.Unlock()

    if a.emailSender != nil {
        a.emailSender(errorMessage)
    }
}

// RWMutex

type RWMutexErrorNotifier struct {
    rwMutex     sync.RWMutex
    emailSender func(string)
}

var _ ErrorNotifier = (*RWMutexErrorNotifier)(nil)

func (a *RWMutexErrorNotifier) SetEmailSenderService(emailSender func(string)) {
    a.rwMutex.Lock()
    defer a.rwMutex.Unlock()

    a.emailSender = emailSender
}

func (a *RWMutexErrorNotifier) SendErrorMessage(errorMessage string) {
    a.rwMutex.RLock()
    defer a.rwMutex.RUnlock()

    if a.emailSender != nil {
        a.emailSender(errorMessage)
    }
}

// Atomic Boolean

type AtomicBooleanErrorNotifier struct {
    emailerIsSet atomic.Bool
    emailSender  func(string)
}

var _ ErrorNotifier = (*AtomicBooleanErrorNotifier)(nil)

func (a *AtomicBooleanErrorNotifier) SetEmailSenderService(emailSender func(string)) {
    defer a.emailerIsSet.Store(true)

    a.emailSender = emailSender
}

func (a *AtomicBooleanErrorNotifier) SendErrorMessage(errorMessage string) {
    if a.emailerIsSet.Load() {
        a.emailSender(errorMessage)
    }
}

// NOT A SOLUTION: racy no locking solution - just for benchmarking

type RacyNoGoodErrorNotifier struct {
    emailSender func(string)
}

var _ ErrorNotifier = (*RacyNoGoodErrorNotifier)(nil)

func (a *RacyNoGoodErrorNotifier) SetEmailSenderService(emailSender func(string)) {
    a.emailSender = emailSender
}

func (a *RacyNoGoodErrorNotifier) SendErrorMessage(errorMessage string) {
    if a.emailSender != nil {
        a.emailSender(errorMessage)
    }
}

// Demo run

const allConcurrent = "all concurrent"
const sequentialSingleCore = "sequential single core"
const sequentialAllCores = "sequential all cores"

func Run(n int, runner ErrorNotifier, runType string) {
    emailSender := func(emailMessage string) {
        // sending email...
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    switch runType {
    case allConcurrent:
        wg.Add(n * runtime.NumCPU())

        for i := 0; i < n*runtime.NumCPU(); i++ {
            go func() {
                runner.SendErrorMessage("ALARM!")
                wg.Done()
            }()
        }
    case sequentialAllCores:
        wg.Add(runtime.NumCPU())

        for i := 0; i < runtime.NumCPU(); i++ {
            go func() {
                for j := 0; j < n; j++ {
                    runner.SendErrorMessage("ALARM!")
                }
                wg.Done()
            }()
        }
    case sequentialSingleCore:
        wg.Add(1)

        go func() {
            for j := 0; j < n*runtime.NumCPU(); j++ {
                runner.SendErrorMessage("ALARM!")
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
    default:
        panic("unknown mode")
    }

    runner.SetEmailSenderService(emailSender)

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Benchmarks:

```golang
package main

import "testing"

func BenchmarkRacyNoGoodConcurrently(b *testing.B) {
    Run(b.N, &RacyNoGoodErrorNotifier{}, allConcurrent)
}

func BenchmarkAtomicBooleanConcurrently(b *testing.B) {
    Run(b.N, &AtomicBooleanErrorNotifier{}, allConcurrent)
}

func BenchmarkRWMutexConcurrently(b *testing.B) {
    Run(b.N, &RWMutexErrorNotifier{}, allConcurrent)
}

func BenchmarkMutexConcurrently(b *testing.B) {
    Run(b.N, &MutexErrorNotifier{}, allConcurrent)
}

func BenchmarkRacyNoGoodSequentiallyAllCores(b *testing.B) {
    Run(b.N, &RacyNoGoodErrorNotifier{}, sequentialAllCores)
}

func BenchmarkAtomicBooleanSequentiallyAllCores(b *testing.B) {
    Run(b.N, &AtomicBooleanErrorNotifier{}, sequentialAllCores)
}

func BenchmarkRWMutexSequentiallyAllCores(b *testing.B) {
    Run(b.N, &RWMutexErrorNotifier{}, sequentialAllCores)
}

func BenchmarkMutexSequentiallyAllCores(b *testing.B) {
    Run(b.N, &MutexErrorNotifier{}, sequentialAllCores)
}

func BenchmarkRacyNoGoodSequentiallySingleCore(b *testing.B) {
    Run(b.N, &RacyNoGoodErrorNotifier{}, sequentialSingleCore)
}

func BenchmarkAtomicBooleanSequentiallySingleCore(b *testing.B) {
    Run(b.N, &AtomicBooleanErrorNotifier{}, sequentialSingleCore)
}

func BenchmarkRWMutexSequentiallySingleCore(b *testing.B) {
    Run(b.N, &RWMutexErrorNotifier{}, sequentialSingleCore)
}

func BenchmarkMutexSequentiallySingleCore(b *testing.B) {
    Run(b.N, &MutexErrorNotifier{}, sequentialSingleCore)
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised `atomic.Bool` isn't more like 10x to 20x faster than taking any kind of lock with one reader thread, and much better than that with more than one reader thread.  Any locking will create contention between readers for access to a cache line (containing the lock), vs. pure read-only readers scaling perfectly because the cache line containing the bool can be in MESI Shared state in the L1d caches of multiple cores at once, so all thread can read in parallel with zero contention.  (And no atomic RMW to take a lock.)

Comment: On x86, taking / releasing a lock repeatedly can go at maybe 1 iteration per 20 cycles with no contention (throughput of `lock xchg [mem], reg`), and of course much worse if a different thread was the last one to release the lock so the cache line is invalid on this core, in Modified state on another.  vs. pure loads being able to run 2 per clock cycle.  IDK how much loop overhead you have besides checking the bool, but it doesn't look like a huge amount?  Anyway, AArch64 is different from x86, but it can't avoid contention created by locking.

Comment: You are right! I refactored the benchmarks and added the racy solution with no locks as a baseline. Apparently, the `atomic.Bool` solution is only marginally slower than no locks at all.

Comment: Yup, that's what I'd expect.  On x86 it compiles to the same instruction as a plain load (but the compiler can't keep in a register and hoist it out of a loop.)  On AArch64, `ldar` is an acquire load that doesn't need any barrier instructions, only as strongly ordered as necessary for [acquire](https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/) and seq_cst (earlier SC stores in the same thread can't reorder with it, but everything else earlier can.)  (Or 32-bit ARM, it would need a load + barrier, which is slower but still scales perfectly with more threads reading in parallel).

Comment: Is your benchmark running multiple reader threads in parallel?  I'd have expected the speed difference to be higher from ping-ponging around the cache line containing the RWMutex, vs. everything hitting in L1d cache for the `atomic.Bool` since it's truly read-only.

Comment: In your last benchmark, where they're taking 285 or 318 or 345 ns, did you start multiple writer threads as well?  Or is there some false-sharing or something?  The no-locking and `atomic.Bool` should still be like 2 ns per operation, about the same as before, unless you changed how much work counts for an iteration.  The code you show isn't the actual benchmark, I think, since it only runs a small number of times?

Comment: So, I made benchmarks with 3 modes: all readers are in single goroutine, one reader goroutine per core, and every routine in their own goroutine. The reason why the no-locking and `atomic.Bool` converge with the mutexes is probably because the sheer number of starting goroutines have a lot of overhead, and the locking (or no-locking) contributes very little to the execution. Also, the writer is still single with a single write.

Comment: I added the 'concurrent all cores' option for comparison as the sequential option uses only 1 core and concurrent one is using all the available cores. So this is like a middle ground of some sort, where the reads are sequential, but for every available core there is a separate reader.

Comment: Interestingly, the `atomic.Boolean` option is the fastest on `sequential with all cores available` but the mutexes are the fastest when used sequentially/single core

Comment: I don't really know Go (I'm here for the [atomic] tag), but presumably starting a goroutine is somewhat similar to either starting an OS-level thread or communicating with an existing worker thread somehow.  So yeah, at least as expensive as a lock makes sense.  The 3.7 ns vs. 1900 or 1500 ns is about what I was expecting for parallel readers with perfect scaling to all cores with `atomic.Bool` vs. all contending to take an RWlock.

Comment: Interesting that an RWMutex is slower than a plain Mutex for this. Reading one bool is so trivially cheap (and it always stays hot in cache unless it's in the same line as the mutex) that it's just ownership of the cache holding the lock that matters; perhaps macOS / Go manage to make the unlocks cheaper with a plain lock, and that balances out not being able to overlap?

Comment: *but the mutexes are the fastest when used sequentially/single core* - Your data shows that the atomic is the fastest for all 3 situations: Concurrently / SequentiallyAllCores / SequentiallySingleCore.  Which is what I'd expect; if it's not being written, it's just a pure load that hits in L1d cache, strictly less overhead than taking any kind of mutex.  (If it is being written concurrently, it's still cheaper than taking a mutex, but just a bit instead of 10x or 1000x faster.)

Comment: Yeah, I was not clear: `atomic.Bool` is the fastest in all modes, but mutexes are performing the best when used sequentially/single core mode. Intersting, why is that?

Comment: Ah, yes.  Like I talked about in my first comments under your initial answer, the atomic RMW involved in locking a mutex is a lot faster if the cache line is already exclusively owned by this core, so it doesn't have to wait for a Read For Ownership to get the cache line from some other core that unlocked it last.  The cache line stays hot in this cores L1d cache, no inter-core latency, only the cost of making the RMW atomic.  Also no contention from other cores wanting to take it from us.  Acquiring an RWMutex still involves an atomic increment or exchange on the mutex.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol re: coherent shared cache.  (Although modern CPUs don't use a shared bus with snooping, they use a "directory" that keeps track of which core might own each line and thus needs to get an invalidate or share request)